# how to add multiple items to a key in vba

Tags: vba, excel

i'm new to vba and i was trying to make a program to do add multiple items to a key.

Eg:

Table

```
Name               Date             Time
XYZ                20               4
ABC                21               5
XYZ                22               6
```

and then if the names are repeated, then column values to the previous one...like:

```
Name              Date             Time            Date          Time
XYZ                20               4               22            6
ABC                21               5
```

i've done sorting and adding the sum of duplicate values for a single item value but i'm finding it hard to do this for multivalued item. So plz do help out!!

Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry to say but I've this three times now and still can't work out what you're trying to achieve / what your question is. Might want to expand on what you're trying to do and what you've done so far.

Comment: You need to post the code you've already tried to make.

Comment: I am really sorry that my question was not clear. All I'm trying to do is...if a duplicate name appears in the names column(in the above case is XYZ) then I want to replace that duplicate row by adding up its items (in the above table is Date and Time column)to the original row..so that there is no duplicate name. So as there is 2 records of XYZ, the second record is added to the first record, but in the different column. I've searched a lot but haven't got a clue how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub t()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim Tempsheet As Worksheet
Dim c As Range


Set Tempsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
     rng = .UsedRange.Address
    .UsedRange.Sort key1:=.Range("b1"), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=.Range("c1"), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    .UsedRange.Columns(1).Copy
    Tempsheet.Range("a1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Tempsheet.Columns(1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

        For Each cell In Tempsheet.Range("a1:a" & Tempsheet.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Cells
            i = i + 1
                If i <> 1 Then
                    With .Range(rng)
                        Set c = .Find(what:=cell.Value, after:=.Range("a1"), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                        firstAddress = c.Address
                            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                                Do
                                    j = j + 1
                                        If j <> 1 Then
                                            k = k + 1
                                            .Range(c.Offset(0, 1), c.Offset(0, 2)).Copy
                                            .Range(firstAddress).Offset(0, (k * 2) + 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
                                            .Range(firstAddress).Offset(-1, (k * 2) + 1) = "Date"
                                            .Range(firstAddress).Offset(-1, (k * 2) + 2) = "Time"
                                            c.EntireRow.ClearContents
                                        End If
                                    Set c = .FindNext(c)
                                Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
                            End If

                    End With

                End If
                        j = 0
        Next cell
    .UsedRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End With
Tempsheet.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: I am sorry but this code is not working for more than 2 duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing an elaborate program for something that is a basic part of the Excel functionality. It is called Pivot tables.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table
- http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html

Comment: but this tutorial does not tell about adding the items of a key to a new column as mentioned in the example above.